# magento 2 translate shipping method title

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, shipping, shipping-methods, localisation

I am trying to convertshipping method title but it's not working.

I am using porto theme for magento 2. In theme there is Folder i18n. for free shipping method i have placed title **FRee Shippings**  now i want to translate this text to custom text **Free Shippings for you**  from en_US.csv file but it's not working.  Also,  for german store i have added german Title. but when i switch to german store it doesn't translate the shipping Title to german.  it shows in english.

[image]

How can i translate shipping title?

Comment: "Free Shipping", "Custom Free Shipping Text"

Comment: You can change the title for each store from admin.

Comment: @SejalShah  Yes,  i can change it from admin store wise but  when i change the store on front end it doesn't show up text entered for that paticular store.  It shows english text for all stores while i have already added german text for german store  in shipping method title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research i found solution of this myself.

In my magento 2 installation i have 3 languages English, German and NL
despite all correct efforts it wasn't working so i did deploy using below commands and it started working.

```
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
```

Here in above code done deploy for each store.

After running above code changes i did for translation reflecting on frontend.

Comment: You can do all these in one command as well. 

 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US nl_NL de_DE

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you view the store at checkout page, store view should still remain in German,

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Secondly, did you try doing below steps :

1. Add German title in German store view from admin panel store configuration
2. Save the title and clear the cache
3. Reload the page on frontend